# Saving URL string column in psql database is causing Rails 3.2 to hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Trying to save an image url for example

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51d2Qu4RGFL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg
```

My Migration:

```
t.string   "promo_url"
```

My Form:

```
<i class="icon-link"></i><%= f.text_field :promo_url, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Image URL" %>
```

hangs inexplicably and silently at Event#Create:

```
@event.save
```

Trace:

```
Request
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 12 ORDER BY name LIMIT 1
Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "64"]]
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

Thanks for any help -- I've never seen rails server hang like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a url validation that was accurate for a domain url but not an image url.

```
@url = /^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)?$/ 
validates :link, :promo_url :format => { :with => @url }, allow_blank:true
```